Is "Alice loves candies" actually necessary for "Alice loves all sweet foods"?
This is the 10th question from this link and its answer is at link.
 A:Alice loves candies. 
 B:Alice loves all sweet foods.


I am trying to identify if A is a logically necessary condition (LNC) for B, and whether A is a logically sufficient condition (LSC) for B.
In my opinion:

Alice loves candies does not imply that Alice loves all sweet foods. So, A is not a sufficient condition for B

Alice does not love all sweet foods (she may like some sweet foods but not all) does not imply that Alice does not love candies. So, A is not a necessary condition for B.


However, the answer key says that A is a necessary condition for B.
Where is my mistake?

Do you consider sweet candy to be food?

I think It is about sweet food not just food.

Sour candies are a thing, and I don't believe a lover of sweet food must love them.

@jwodder: On the flip side, a statement "Person likes [things of a category]" doesn't imply that there couldn't possibly exist something in that category that the person wouln't like, nor even that the person has tried something in the category that they didn't like.  Indeed, such a statement would be more descriptive of a scenario where the person had tried 100 things in a category and liked 99 of them, than any scenario where the person had in fact never tried any, even if the person would in fact like all of them.

Your mistake is that for $A$ to be a necessary condition for $B$ it must hold that $\neg A\Rightarrow\neg B$ (if the necessary condition is not met, then the condition for which it is necessary is also not met) instead of $\neg B\Rightarrow \neg A$. The latter would mean that $A$ is sufficient for $B$ since it is equivalent to $A\Rightarrow B$, which you have correctly argued to be false.
In our case, if Alice does not love candies, then she does not love all sweet foods, so $\neg A\Rightarrow\neg B$ is true and thus $A$ is necessary for $B$.

What If alice does not love candies ,but she may like cakes ( a sweet food) ?

Then she doesn't love all sweet food. That is, $B$ is not true, and neither is $A$, so $\neg A\Rightarrow\neg B$ holds.

does it mean that she doesn't love all sweet food is logically equivalent to  she loves some sweet food?

@noviceprogrammer no.

@noviceprogrammer It's logically consistent with it (as in, there is a possible state of affairs where that is true: she likes cakes but not candies).

Hi, I have another question. A.  All women pay taxes.  and B. Anyone who does not pay taxes is not a woman..  I am able to determine the A is necessary  condition of B through through the implication B->A but not able to unable to determine through the implication ~A->~B,  as I am struggling to understand the meaning of negation of  A . Does negation of A implies that some woman does   pay taxes ?

The negation of "everyone does" is "at least one person doesn't". In your case: $\neg A$: "At least one woman doesn't pay taxes". Which does not imply that some women do. If no woman paid taxes, then there is also at least one who doesn't (as long as there exist any women at all). But it may also be that some women do pay taxes. The only relevant thing is that at least one doesn't.

Hi @Vercassivelaunos, Sorry for bothering you again but I think should take a help. I am kind of  got stuck in this topic. My first problem is  I am struggling to find negation, I have tried to search books that covers finding  negation of general English sentences  like I provided, so that I can practice, but not able to find as such , and second problem is I still fails to determine  if the condition is sufficient or necessary, for this also I have tried to find a book that contains practice exercise through which I can clear my doubts but didn't find as such book.

@Vercassivelaunos,  Could you please share some advice, or recommend any books so that I can move forward ?

I'm sorry, but I don't have any relevant resources I could recommend.

It seems like the analysis is made more complicated by thinking about negations.
More simply, consider the implication $B \implies A$; that is, "If Alice loves all sweet foods, then Alice loves candies". This is true, given that candies are a type of sweet food.
In most presentations, this is the actual definition for $A$ to be a necessary condition for $B$.

In some sense it is more complicated, but in another sense, it may be easier to grasp for a beginner, since in everyday intuition, "necessity" has a kind of sequential component: First $A$ has to hold, then $B$ can hold. Of course, such a component is not really there in pure logic, but it may be easier to understand if the logic is in line with it. In that case, an implication where the necessary condition is on the left would be favorable. However, it is certainly a good idea to present both versions, which is why I also upvoted your answer.

I have always read that to prove necessary conditions, we have to show absence/falsity of A guarantees of absence/falsity of B. I was not aware I prove in this way too.

@noviceprogrammer: What I have here is the standard definition of necessity. E.g., Wikipedia: "For example, in the conditional statement: 'If P then Q', Q is necessary for P, because the truth of Q is guaranteed by the truth of P." See also Rosen Discrete Mathematics Sec. 1.1, Ross/Wright Discrete Mathematics Sec. 2.1, Balakrishnan Introductory Discrete Mathematics Sec. 0.4, etc.

@noviceprogrammer The two are equivalent via contrapositive: $(B\Rightarrow A)\Leftrightarrow(\neg A\Rightarrow\neg B)$.


A:Alice loves candies. 
B:Alice loves all sweet foods.

I am trying to identify if A is a logically necessary condition (LNC) for B.
the answer key says that A is a necessary condition for B.

A: $∀x\,(Cx → Lx)$
B: $∀x\,(Sx → Lx)$
Let M denote the axiom ‘All candies are sweet foods’: $$∀x\,(Cx → Sx).\tag M$$
Now, $$∀x\,(Sx → Lx) \quad→\quad ∀x\,(Cx → Lx)\tag✘\\\text B\quad\to\quad \text A$$ isn't logically valid, so A isn't logically necessary for B (B does not logically imply A).
However, $$∀x\,(Cx → Sx) \;\to\;\Big(∀x\,(Sx → Lx) \;→\;∀x\,(Cx → Lx)\Big)\tag✓\\\text M\;\to\; \big(\text B\;\to\;\text A\big)$$ is logically valid, so we can say that under axiom M, A is necessary for B (B implies A).

Alice does not love all sweet foods (she may like some sweet foods but not all) doesn't imply that Alice does not love candies.
So, A isn't necessary for B.

You correctly observed that (even under assumption M), ‘Alice doesn't love every sweet food’ doesn't imply ‘Alice doesn't love any candy’, that is, that the following isn't logically valid:
$$∀x\, (Cx→ Sx)\;→\;  \Big(\lnot\forall x\, (Sx\to Lx) \;→\; ∀x\,(Cx→¬ Lx)\Big)\tag✘\\\text M\;→\;\Big(\text{not B}\;\to\; ∀x\,(Cx→¬Lx)\Big)$$
(note that $∀x\,(Cx→¬Lx)$ is not equivalent to ‘Alice doesn't love every candy’ (not A) ).
You then made a logical leap to conclude that A isn't necessary for B (which would in turn imply that A isn't logically necessary for B). And obviously your observation doesn't support that A is necessary for B either.

@noviceprogrammer Is 'she doesn't love all sweet food' logically equivalent to 'she loves some sweet food'? $\quad$ The former phrasing is slightly ambiguous, but likely means 'she doesn't love every sweet food' (i.e., 'there is some sweet food that she doesn't love'), rather than 'she doesn't love any sweet food' (i.e., 'there is no sweet food that she loves').

From an English-language perspective, the sentence "Alice likes candies" could be true even if the only candies that Alice likes are too sour to be classified as "sweet foods".

@noviceprogrammer P.S. I added a link to show that A isn't logically necessary for B. $\quad$ If we take what the exercise's author calls "LNC (logically necessary condition)" to simply mean "necessary condition under the usual real-world assumptions", then the answer key's true assertion (which agrees with all our answers) has indeed addressed the exercise.

@supercat Is your point that "Alice likes candies" doesn't mean "Alice likes all candies"? In the given exercise (and for the OP's needs), it's perfectly reasonable to translate the former as the latter. I see ambiguity only when the OP tried to verbally negate A and B, which is tricky (and unnecessary).

@ryang: As stated in my answer, the sentence may have multiple reasonable interpretations.  Further, also as stated in my answer, the validity of the inference depends upon intersection of "candies" and "sweet things" being non-empty, and/or the subset of "candies" that excludes "sweet things" being empty (which assumption(s) is/are required depends upon the interpretation of the sentence).  Is there anything unclear about the answer?

The English-language statement "Alice loves candies" may either be taken to imply that Alice loves all candies, that Alice loves at least some candies, or most typically that Alice loves whatever subset of candies are of interest in the context where the statement is made (e.g. if Alice is in front of a candy bowl when someone makes the statement, that would indicate  that Alice likes the kinds of candies that are in the bowl).
The Statement "Alice loves at least some candies" will be a necessary condition for B if one assumes that there exists a non-empty set of sweet things that are candies.  The statement "Alice loves all candies" will be a necessary condition if the set of candies that are not sweet things is empty.  The statement "Alice loves candies" will not be necessary condition if either (1) there might not exist any sweet candies, or (2) the statement means "Alice loves all candies", but there might exist non-sweet candies that Alice doesn't like.

From your answer, I'm concluding that whether A is necessary for B depends on the underlying assumptions, which in turn means that A being necessary for B is not so by pure logical force, i.e., A is not tautologically necessary for B.

@ryang: A complication of trying to do logic with natural-language examples is that certain kinds of assumptions are often taken for granted (e.g. that the set of candies is a subset of the set of sweet things).  Taking such things for granted can promote brevity, and shouldn't necessarily be viewed as a defect, but understanding logical relationships may require understanding the assumptions made by a problem statement.

I was making explicit your answer's connection to the given exercise ("identify if A is a tautologically/logically necessary condition (LNC) for B"), while you've been waxing lyrical.

@ryang: In order for common interpretations of the phrase "Alice loves candies" to be true, one would need an axiom not listed in your answer: "The set of candies is non-empty".  While the statements "Alice loves all candies" and "All candies are sweet foods" would be vacuously true if the set of candies was empty, the given statement was "Alice loves candies", which would often be interpreted as implying, at minimum, that the subset of candies that Alice loves is non-empty, which would be false if the set of candies was empty.

I don't know why you keep cross-linking independent comments under our answers, rehashing your points, imagining disagreement (?) and making oblique insinuations. Please just read my comments/answer for what they say (and feel free to refute anything that I actually wrote!). (Ironically, choosing to reply only to pertinent points was to minimise clutter.)

@ryang: Did any other answers recognize that the statement "Alice loves candies", as typically understood, would be only be a necessary condition if the set of candies cannot be empty?    I didn't want to have my answer address only that case while ignoring all others, but thought that case needed to be included.  Should I more clearly indicate that my answer is intended to recognize the need for an assumption not mentioned by others?

It is very clear that your answer is highlighting alternative (implicit) assumptions underlying the assertion, "A is necessary for B". P.S. Here I'm not commenting whether those specific assumptions are reasonable or within the scope of the given exercise (which honestly in the first place shouldn't have to rely on any assumption if it truly means to ask about tautological necessity—ok, I'm being a broken record, Apologies!).

@ryang: Okay; I think we're in violent agreement with each other.  >:*3.  I know that some people find it easier to reason about tangible real-world things like sweets than symbols like X and Y, but it would be helpful if people writing problems could share a named set of common assumptions, so problems could explicitly state "AcmeFoo assumptions apply" or "AcmeFoo assumptions do not apply".
